# TabBarController - add same view multiple times for different days of the week?

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbarcontroller

I want to develop an app that shows the menu of the days of the week from Monday to Friday. I managed to add five tabs to the controller, although these are displayed as five *different* tabs. Therefore, all labels and so on need to be added 5 times.

The view that displays the data itself is always the same and just the data itself differs. I'd like to design only one view, add it 5 times and decide in the code itself which data is displayed.

Is this somehow possible?

**Solution**

After trying out I found a solution that worked for me. The ViewController I want to be displayed five times must have an identifier.

```
let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! UITabBarController

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var vc_array = [StudiersaalTableViewController]()

for i in 0..<5 {
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("studiersaalTabBar") as! StudiersaalTableViewController
    vc.currentDay = i
    vc_array.append(vc)
}

var i = 0
for vc in vc_array {
    let title = NSDate.getDayOfWeekAsString(i)
    vc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: title.substringToIndex(title.startIndex.advancedBy(2)), image: nil, tag: i)
    i++
}
controller.viewControllers = vc_array
controller.selectedIndex = NSDate().getDayOfWeek()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one view controller subclass with an enum property that contains the days of the week. Assuming your tab bar controller is the root view controller, it's probably easiest to create the view controllers in the AppDelegate, like so:

```
let mondayVC = WeekViewController(day: .Monday)
let tuesdayVC = WeekViewController(day: .Tuesday)
// etc..

tabBarController.viewControllers = [mondayVC, tuesdayVC]
```

then in your view controller subclass (WeekViewController or whatever you want to call it) you can set the tab bar item image and title. and then based on whichever day-of-week property it has you can determine what info to display.

Comment: It's not in the root view controller. The root view is a table view with a few menu points. If I select the first one, the TabBarController should display the tabs and its contents. I'm not quite sure how to do this whole thing with the storyboard... I tried to implement the code you've written in the prepareSegue-function but unfortunately, when I select the first menu entry, an empty navigation controller (or something like that) is displayed.